# Calling top.window.history.back() from iframe doesn't work in FF

Tags: javascript, firefox, web

I have a web page which is posting a form with file to the server. The response is a javascript code like:

```
top.window.history.back();
```

So the idea is that I have SPA web application, and when user uploaded file it the page should navigate to the previous view.

It is working fine in Chrome and IE, but it doesn't work in FF (version 20.0 on OS X).

Any ideas why it is not working and is there any workarounds?

Comment: Any message in the console? I cannot test until tomorrow. Way is spa and what triggers the script?

Comment: No messages in console. SPA-single page application. I have a form on the page which has target attribute pointing to iframe. When user posted form - resulting javascript is executed inside the iframe.

Comment: Very strange. Suggestion is to set a cookie and monitor it in the parent

Comment: Why is there window.top and top.window? I use window.top but noticed the latter is valid.  Who came up with this stuff??